# Xcode10.0 when import .h file，Xcode crash

Tags: xcode

I just update my Xcode to 10.0;

After that, when i import a .h file while inputing the file name, the Xcode crash,100%, anyone else meet this question?

macOS High Sierra
version:10.13.6
Xcode version:10.0

[image]

Comment: this occured after a update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the resolved method.

In Xcode Menu,click File->Workspace Setting

then Change the Build System From New Build System to Legacy Build System

[image]

Comment: yay! worked like a charm. my xcode verison is 10.0 and it crashed when ever i tried to import a header or any framework. This solution gives me relief thanks @Michael Yang

Answer (score 0):

Change the header search path in target build setting to use absolute path or environment variable instead of relative path.